# Min of Order Statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, order-statistics

I am trying to solve the question which is below. However, I cannot find the expectation value because of the function that I found cannot be integrated. I am not sure if I am doing a mistake or not. If I do, please show my mistake.

**QUESTION**

Let $(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ be a random sample of i.i.d. random variables distributed as:

$$f (x, \theta) =\begin{cases}e^{\theta−x},& x ≥ θ\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

1. Find the distribution of the statistics $X_{(1)}= \min_i\{X_i\}$.
2. Find $E(X_{(1)})$ and $\text{Var}(X_{(1)})$.

**MY SOLUTION**

$F_\min(x) = F_{(1)}(x) = 1-P(X_\min > x)\\
              = 1-P(X_1>x, X_2>x,…,X_n>x)\\
              = 1-(1-F_1(x))(1-F_2(x))…(1-F_n(x))\\ 
              = 1-(1-F(x))^n$

$f_\min(x) = -\frac{d}{dx}[(1-F(x))^n] = n[1-F(x)]^{n-1}f(x)$

where the $F(x) =-\exp(-x+\theta)$ and $f(x) =\exp(-x+ \theta)$

So $f_{x_{(1)}}(x) = n[1+\exp(-x+\theta)]^{n-1}\exp(-x+\theta)$

and $E[X_{(1)}] =\int xn[1-exp(-x+\theta)]^{n-1}(-\exp(-x+\theta)) dx$

Comment: Welcome to the website. Use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math equations in future. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made an error in calculating $F(x)\ne-e^{\theta-x}$.

This is because $F(x)=P(X_i\le x)=\int_\theta^xf(x,\theta)dx=\color{red}1-e^{\theta-x}$ when $x>\theta$ and $0$ otherwise. You missed the $1$.